# QGIS 3.28.3 Firenze - How to show info in a GeoJSON file imported as a raster next to the concerned points

Tags: qgis, labeling, data

I'm having problems with GeoJSON files from the renass.unistra.fr/ site. Those contains seismic data build this way:

```
{"features":[
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[0.1792750955,42.96690369,-7.830163479],"type":"Point"},"id":"fr2023lbrxdm","properties":{"automatic":false,"depth":7.830163479,"description":{"en":"Earthquake of magnitude 0.8, near of Pau","fr":"Tremblement de terre de magnitude 0.8, proche de Pau"},"latitude":42.96690369,"longitude":0.1792750955,"mag":0.8427590631,"magType":"MLv","time":"2023-02-10T16:10:22.031211Z","type":"earthquake","url":{"en":"https://renass.unistra.fr/en/events/fr2023lbrxdm","fr":"https://renass.unistra.fr/fr/evenements/fr2023lbrxdm"}},"type":"Feature"},
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[7.633597374,48.27806473,-11.00080776],"type":"Point"},"id":"fr2023lbrbdo","properties":{"automatic":false,"depth":11.00080776,"description":{"en":"Earthquake of magnitude 2.1, near of Colmar","fr":"Tremblement de terre de magnitude 2.1, proche de Colmar"},"latitude":48.27806473,"longitude":7.633597374,"mag":2.07072404,"magType":"MLv","time":"2023-02-10T12:02:31.394255Z","type":"earthquake","url":{"en":"https://renass.unistra.fr/en/events/fr2023lbrbdo","fr":"https://renass.unistra.fr/fr/evenements/fr2023lbrbdo"}},"type":"Feature"},
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[2.893254757,42.81396866,-18.68663979],"type":"Point"},"id":"fr2023lbqroa","properties":{"automatic":false,"depth":18.68663979,"description":{"en":"Earthquake of magnitude 1.1, near of Perpignan","fr":"Tremblement de terre de magnitude 1.1, proche de Perpignan"},"latitude":42.81396866,"longitude":2.893254757,"mag":1.079549742,"magType":"MLv","time":"2023-02-10T10:14:24.385364Z","type":"earthquake","url":{"en":"https://renass.unistra.fr/en/events/fr2023lbqroa","fr":"https://renass.unistra.fr/fr/evenements/fr2023lbqroa"}},"type":"Feature"},
{"geometry":{"coordinates":[-0.5354073644,43.09825516,-9.183314323],"type":"Point"},"id":"fr2023lbqgmx","properties":{"automatic":false,"depth":9.183314323,"description":{"en":"Earthquake of magnitude 1.2, near of Pau","fr":"Tremblement de terre de magnitude 1.2, proche de Pau"},"latitude":43.09825516,"longitude":-0.5354073644,"mag":1.229229673,"magType":"MLv","time":"2023-02-10T08:09:59.099103Z","type":"earthquake","url":{"en":"https://renass.unistra.fr/en/events/fr2023lbqgmx","fr":"https://renass.unistra.fr/fr/evenements/fr2023lbqgmx"}},"type":"Feature"}],
"type":"FeatureCollection"}
```

(I added returns for better readbility)

At some point for every shake, I have the exact time it occured according to the site, how can I show it in the map I see in QGIS next to the points I am studying?

[image: map of seisms]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the labels for the layer to use the `time` field:

[image]